# Can't get secs from CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, datetime, timestamp, sql-server-2012

When I try to do `select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` I get `2013-09-06 13:55:17.217` in table form. But when I try to do `print CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` I get `Sep  6 2013  1:58PM` I don't get secs here. what is the problem, did I make any wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT convert(varchar, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 113)
```

or

```
SELECT FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss')
```

See [here](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2012/format-function-vs-convert-function.aspx) for more formating options

Answer (score 1):

From [PRINT (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx)

@ local_variable

> Is a variable of any **valid character data type**. **@local_variable
>   must be char, nchar, varchar, or nvarchar, or it must be able to be
>   implicitly converted to those data types**.

So thisa would just be how SQL Server implicitly converts the value to a VARCHAR/NVARCHAR to PRINT

Have a look at [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) using the default convertion types to change the output format types.